# record(line) terminator in BufferedReader of Java

Tags: java, prepared-statement, bufferedreader, vertica

I am reading from a file from hadoop. The file is delimited by CTRL+B character. I must load these files to vertica database.

I am reading hadoop files line by line and inserts the records using prepared statements. Some of the records in the files contains new line(SOH control character) in their values(eg; address, comments). I am using readLine() on the BufferedReader object to hadoop file. So, it rejects some of the records containing newlines in their columns. It reads these records as two records missing some column values. This causes database to reject them.

The File is delimited by STX(CTRL+B). The columns values containing new lines are having SOH(CTRL+A) inside them. My question is how to read these lines as such. Any help?

Comment: Is there any reason you can't just read directly from HDFS?

Comment: Yes, the vertical hadopp connector is not working properly with vertical 7

Comment: What isn't working? What version of Vertica are you running? What flavor of Hadoop are you running?

Comment: I am using CDH5 and vertica 7. Right now I am using prepared statement s

Comment: Again, **what** isn't working with the connector?

Answer (score 1):

These aren't lines as such in terms of `BufferedReader.readLine()`, and the bytes concerned are not characters in its terms either. You will have to use an `InputStream` and look for the terminators yoursef

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Scanner` class.  You can set the delimiter with [useDelimiter(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#useDelimiter(java.lang.String)) .